Pagerduty is not closing a stack driver incident if it is manually resolved
The following scenario causes an orphaned SD incident:

Stack driver incident triggered off metric
PD is notified
The PD incident is manually resolved AND the metric stops sending data (somewhat of an edge case)
PD does not close the SD incident and it remains forever

The SD alert policy is configured like this:

I don't want incidents to autoclose if data is absent.
PD won't close the SD incident in this scenario probably because SD won't let you close until the rolling window has elapsed.
Is there some way to have PD wait for the SD rolling window to close the incident in this case?

You can configure to  close the incidents on PagerDuty's end. To do this, you need to create a Service Integration in PagerDuty. You can create a service integration by

Going to the Integrations page in PagerDuty> Clicking the Create Integration button> Selecting the Service Integration type

Then enter a name for the integration > Select the Google Cloud Platform service & click the Configure button

Enter your Google Cloud Platform credentials > Select the Incidents tab

Under Acknowledged, select the Close incident checkbox

Under Closed, select the Close incident checkbox > Click the Save button


After creating the Service Integration, the Acknowledge and Close buttons in Google Cloud Monitoring will also close the incidents on PagerDuty's end.
For more information go through this Document which might be helpful.

This is incorrect, probably outdated info. This is the official configuration: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#pagerduty. There also no longer exists a "Google Cloud Platform" integration from what I see.

Go through this Document which will help you in closing the Incident.

If your issue is not solved can you create a new Issue Tracker thread describing your issue. If you have paid support try creating an Issue
